# I'm getting an index which was outside the bounds of the array error

Tags: c#

So, I've made a program that is supposed to collect the amount of numbers you put in and then count them backwards.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace K4_Labb_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Ange antalet heltal du vill lagra i fältet: ");

            int heltal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] i = new int[heltal];

            Console.WriteLine("Ange " + heltal + " heltal: ");

            for (int j = 0; j < i.Length; j++)
            {
                int o = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                i[j] = o;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Talen utskrivna baklänges: " );
            for (int l = i.Length; l > 0; l--)
            {

                Console.Write(i[l]);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error "index was outside the bounds of the array" and I was wondering if anyone could help me out, and explain what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Problem here:

```
        for (int l = i.Length; l > 0; l--)
```

When you have an array of length say `LEN`, then you can only access elements with index `0, 1, 2, ..., LEN-1`.

Comment: So, im a beginner at c#, what is it that i need to change?

Comment: @JonathanHjalmarsson in your loop start with i.length-1 and go till 0 (however including zero, e.g. use >=0)

Answer (score 0):

While printing the array, you were you were starting from one place more than the limit. If the lenght is 5, then the array places will be 0,1,2,3,4.
But in your program while printing you were starting from 5, which was throwing the error and which is correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Ange antalet heltal du vill lagra i fältet: ");

            int heltal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] i = new int[heltal];

            Console.WriteLine("Ange " + heltal + " heltal: ");

            for (int j = 0; j < i.Length; j++)
            {
                int o = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                i[j] = o;

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Talen utskrivna baklänges: ");
            for (int l = i.Length-1; l >= 0; l--)
            {

                Console.Write(i[l]);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: >=0 you may want to use.